# regarding the use of "them"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, articles

> X = any verb ending in ing e.g swimming

> Y = a certain group of people e.g Martians

"What everyone refers to as the habit of X(ing) by the Y, is not what the Y themselves believe them to be."

"Them" is referring to X. If I use 'them' in the second part of the sentence, will it be grammatically correct since "habit of X" seems singular.

Comment: The comma after Aborigines is wrong too. It separates the subject from the verb, as in "The weather today, is wet".

Comment: Since two of the existing answers (one of them my own now) refer to the original quote that you had, I added a note to your edited version. Otherwise, those two answers could be confusing.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's incorrect.

It's not always simple to give a yes-no answer to the question "is there any grammatical error in this sentence". The correctness of pronoun usage often depends on the intended meaning: a pronoun might be grammatically correct with one meaning, but incorrect with another meaning. In that sentence, "them" seems to stand for "dreams", a noun that appears nowhere in the quote. I wouldn't use it that way, regardless of whether it is possible for a reader to interpret the meaning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence fails in terms of both *syntax* and *semantics*.

*Syntactically*, without knowing more about the meaning of the sentence than what is in the sentence, it needs to be changed to the following:

> ✔ What the Europeans refer to as **the habit of dreaming** <sup>(singular)</sup> by the Aborigines **is** <sup>(singular)</sup> not what the Aborigines themselves believe **it** <sup>(*the habit of dreaming*: singular)</sup> to be.

Per syntax alone, this is now correct. And if *it* is interpreted as *the habit of dreaming*, everything is fine.

Based purely on the sentence alone, this is what I believe it has to be changed to; I believe that *they* is a mistake, and it should really be *it*.

---

However, this is stated in the question:

> "Them" is referring to dreams.

This throws the previous analysis into chaos.  First, *them* has to be retained:

> What the Europeans refer to as **the habit of dreaming** <sup>(singular)</sup> by the Aborigines **is** <sup>(singular)</sup> not what the Aborigines themselves believe **them** to be.

But this makes no sense.

---

In the first place, it would not be natural to assume that *them* is referring to *dreams*. The only plural subjects in the sentence are *the Europeans* and *the Aborigines*. Since there are no other plural subjects in the sentence, and it wouldn't make sense for *them* to be referring to one of those groups, it's not clear *what* it could be referring to; it looks like a mistake.

In essence, these are the possible interpretations, with the pronoun being replaced by a noun. And *dreams* is only being provided as the third noun because that's what it's been stated to be:

> 1. What the Europeans refer to as **the habit of dreaming** <sup>(singular)</sup> by the Aborigines **is** <sup>(singular)</sup> not what the Aborigines themselves believe *the Europeans* to be.
>
> 2. What the Europeans refer to as **the habit of dreaming** <sup>(singular)</sup> by the Aborigines **is** <sup>(singular)</sup> not what the Aborigines themselves believe *the Aborigines* to be.
>
> 3. What the Europeans refer to as **the habit of dreaming** <sup>(singular)</sup> by the Aborigines **is** <sup>(singular)</sup> not what the Aborigines themselves believe *dreams* to be.

None of those sentences are meaningful.

Looking at the third sentence, which is said to be correct, it can be simplified in the following way:

> ？ The habit of dreaming is not what dreams are.

While this is syntactically correct, it's not an understandable sentence—at least not on its own without further context to explain how it can make sense. Adding back in all of the qualifiers of the original sentence doesn't help it to make any more sense.

---

*If* you can somehow make it known that *them* is referring to dreams, then you could say that the sentence is *syntactical*. (And the fact that it's syntactical would have no bearing on the fact that *the habit if dreaming* is singular.) However, it still wouldn't be *meaningful*—at least not without further context that could make it so.

---

If *they* really does refer to *dreams* and not to *the habit of dreaming*, then here is one possible way of rephrasing the sentence so that it makes sense on every level:

> ✔ What the Europeans refer to as the habit of dreaming by the Aborigines does not involve what the Aborigines themselves believe to be dreams.

But without additional context beyond the single sentence, I can't say if that would be a valid rephrasing or not.

Comment: @Safwaan In that following sentence, _them_ quite unambiguously refers to the Aborigines (or rather, to their leader), not to dreams.

Comment: @Safwaan Knowing the sentences that came before and after might have made a difference. As it was, I only had the single sentence to look at. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is too ambiguous.  You would repeat phases to be clear.  This is because the sentence implies that the notion (definition) of what Aborigines believe dreams to be, is not stated in this sentence.  Because of the allusion, the things in this sentence must be more specific and concrete.

> When Europeans refer to the 'habit of dreaming', it is not the same thing as what the Aborigines believe of dreaming."